# Using wxPython elements outside the class?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to do something with a wx element from outside the class:

```
def doStuff(uselessVariableIsUseless):
    myListbox.Set(myList)

class myWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        myListbox = wx.ListBox(parent = self, pos = (320, 30), size = (300, 500))
```

I've also tried globalizing myListbox inside `def __init__()`, and using `myWindow.myListbox`, etc, but I still get `NameError: global name 'myListbox' is not defined`. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign to `self.myListbox` to make it a property of the instance. You can then pass the instance to the `doStuff` method and access it via `<object>.myListbox`:

```
def doStuff(win):
    win.myListbox.Set(myList)

class myWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        self.myListbox = wx.ListBox(parent = self, pos = (320, 30), size = (300, 500))

my_win = myWindow(0, 0)
doStuff(my_win)
```

Comment: Those are passed to `__init__` for `parent` and `id` (and before you ask, `self` is assigned the current instance automatically).

Comment: I normally see the parent for a top-level frame set to None instead of zero. You don't need to provide an id and in fact, I wouldn't. If you do, you should use "-1" or wx.ID_ANY, not zero because you should let wxPython set the ids itself so you don't accidentally assign the same id to multiple widgets. The "-1" is a magic number that is equivalent to wx.ID_ANY.